# Proguard behavior change after upgrading gradle, omits classes from built apk

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, proguard

Several days ago I upgraded Gradle plugin in my Android Studio project,
The upgrade was done from **3.3.2** to **4.2.1**

Since that moment the behavior of the ProGuard has changed a bit, librarys that were included in the release apk, are omitted from it now,

The only mention of the missing classes in ProGuard is as follows (showing one example):

```
-dontwarn org.apache.log4j.**
-dontnote org.apache.log4j.**
```

Of course, if I'll add

`-keep org.apache.log4j.**`

or

`-keep public class org.apache.log4j.xx {}`

It will solve the problem and will add the library into the release apk,

It seems that `dontwarn` or '-dontnote' used to tell ProGuard to include these libraries in the release apk?

Do I need to add `-keep` to all library/classes that used to have `-dontwarn` and '-dontnote' in my ProGuard config file?

Does upgrading gradle caused this behavior change?

Thanks ahead

Answer (score 1):

> It seems that dontwarn or '-dontnote' used to tell ProGuard to include these libraries in the release apk?

No, they just told Proguard to not complain to you about issues relating to `org.apache.log4j.**`. They otherwise don't affect what Proguard does.

This is mainly useful if you have a build system that treats warnings as errors so the problems with an external dependency don't take your project.

> Do I need to add -keep to all library/classes that used to have -dontwarn and '-dontnote' in my ProGuard config file?

Well, that's one way of doing things, but it isn't the best. Normally, Proguard/R8 (the new replacement for proguard in the Android Gradle Plugin) is smart enough to figure out which parts of your dependencies are being used and not remove them. That isn't happening here and it might be a good idea to figure out why so you do not blow up the size of your App.

A big culprit is using reflection, in which case you should use annotations to help tell proguard to keep those. https://www.guardsquare.com/manual/configuration/examples#annotated

> Does upgrading gradle caused this behavior change?

Sometimes, yes. Proguard and R8, like many tools, improve in functionality over time. This leads to behavior changes which sometimes lead to difficulties in development. While it's bad that your app no longer compiles well, it's probably good that the tools are trying to be more aggressive in stripping.